# How to make the height of a DIV containing a UL auto expand

Tags: html, css, formatting, height

I am using the HTML below to display a tabbed list (I have simplified it by concentrating on the longest list as this is the one causing my problem). How can I make it so that the `div` that contains the `ul` automatically expands to its height according to the length of the `ul`. `CSS` is below the `HTML`:

```
<div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8">
    <section class="tabs">
        <h2 class="centered">SAMPLE MENU</h2>
        <input id="tab-1" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="tab-selector-1"     checked="checked"    />
        <label for="tab-1" class="tab-label-1">Casual Eating</label>
        <input id="tab-2" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="tab-selector-2" />
        <label for="tab-2" class="tab-label-2">Dining</label>
        <input id="tab-3" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="tab-selector-3" />
        <label for="tab-3" class="tab-label-3">Afternoon Tea</label>
        <input id="tab-4" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="tab-selector-4" />
        <label for="tab-4" class="tab-label-4">Desserts</label>
        <div class="clear-shadow"></div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="content-2">
                <ul class="menu_items">
                    <li>
                        <h3>Wild Boar Bons</h3>
                        <p>wensleydale wild boar, pickled mushrooms & quince</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>Tangled Tiger Prawns</h3>
                        <p>chilli & garlic prawns, straw pastry, spiced coconut broth</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>Wood Pigeon Nest</h3>
                        <p>local wood pigeon, potato & parsnip nest, foraged fruit</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>Avocado Mango Burratta</h3>
                        <p>buffalo mozzarella, alfonso mango, citrus rye toast</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>Seared Black Salmon</h3>
                        <p>cucumber salad, soy, ginger & mirin</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>Rose Veal Rib</h3>
                        <p>aged veal chop, rosemary desiree potato & shallots</p>
                    <li>
                        <h3>Crispy Rabbit Cassoulet</h3>
                        <p>fried leg, loin, chorizo cassoulet & celeriac slaw</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>Morel Butter Turbot</h3>
                        <p>turbot loin poached in morel butter, capers & samphire</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>Wild Garlic Raviolo</h3>
                        <p>green herb pasta, goats cheese, confit shallots</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>Pink Lady Pig</h3>
                        <p>belly & loin, king scallop & apple salad</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>Pecan Maple Goose</h3>
                        <p>wild goose, streaky bacon, roast swede & chesnuts</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>Lobster Fennel Pie</h3>
                        <p>whole lobster tail, saffron mash & baby fennel</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>Girolle Truffle Brioche</h3>
                        <p>girolles, quails eggs, asparagus, black truffle & toasted brioche</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>Pan Fried Fillet</h3>
                        <p>oxtail fritter ,smoked garlic& sirloin butter, roast onion</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

CSS for the above code:

```
.menu_wrapper {
    background: url(../img/bg/light_cream_bg.jpg);
}
.tabs {
    background: url("http://fmkcatering.com/wp-content/themes/fmk/images/grey-bg.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    position: relative;
    margin: 40px auto;
    width: 750px;
}
.tabs input {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 38px;
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tabs label {
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 20px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 187px;
    color: #385c5b;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}
.tabs label:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    display: block;
}
.tabs input:hover + label {
    color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #F90;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
.tabs label:first-of-type {
    z-index: 4;
}
.tab-label-2 {
    z-index: 3;
}
.tab-label-3 {
    z-index: 2;
}
.tab-label-4 {
    z-index: 1;
}
.tabs input:checked + label {
    z-index: 6;
}
.clear-shadow {
    clear: both;
}
.content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 370px;
    z-index: 5;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 3px;
}
.content div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity linear 0.1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity linear 0.1s;
    -o-transition: opacity linear 0.1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity linear 0.1s;
    transition: opacity linear 0.1s;
}
.tabs input.tab-selector-1:checked ~ .content .content-1, .tabs input.tab-selector-2:checked ~ .content .content-2, .tabs input.tab-selector-3:checked ~ .content .content-3, .tabs input.tab-selector-4:checked ~ .content .content-4 {
    z-index: 100;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
    -o-transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
    transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
}
.content div h2, .content div h3 {
    color: #398080;
}
.content div p {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
    color: #777;
    font-family: Cambria, Georgia, serif;
    text-align: center;
}
.menu_items {
    list-style: none outside none !important;
    width: 700px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
.menu_items li {
    float: left;
    width: 340px;
}
.menu_items li h3 {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/QGyJ9/1/

Comment: put it in a http://jsfiddle.net and I will help you.

Comment: Thanks, doing that now.

Comment: Already done for you.

Comment: here is the above code http://jsfiddle.net/Ca3jb/

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the example (sorry, did not realize other people would no longer see the original code -- my first time using jsfiddle).

I had to do various changes:

- remove hard-coded heigh for ".content" (let the browser compute it)
- remove the absolute positioning for ".content div" (not clear why you needed it)
- most importantly added a rule for ".content:after" (this is often used by defining a clearfix class in your CSS, and using it on the appropriate elements

  .content:after {
     content: " ";
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     height: 0;
     clear: both;
     visibility: hidden;
  }

Now the background extends to the bottom of the list

Comment: I have tried applying your edits to my code and when its applied to the full ul it has some wired effects http://jsfiddle.net/a67vZ/

Comment: I would remove the width from '.container' (it should be computed automatically). Not sure what you call weird here. For '.content div' you have set the opacity to 0. This make the item invisible (although 'visibility:hidden' would be better) but still reserves space for it. Presumably you should set 'display:none' instead.

Comment: It would also look much better to add '.tabs label {border:1px solid transparent}' to avoid having the 'Desserts' menu move back and forth when other menus are highlighted

Comment: using "weird" was bad phrasing on my part I apologise, when applying your original changes the following issues arise.

On Casual Eating the box does not shrink, so there is a large amount of space below the li items. 

On Dining there is a large amount of space above and below the li items, this also happens on Afternoon Tea.

And on Desserts every li item is pushed to the bottom of the page, again all this happens without any resizing of the ul

Comment: Did you try seeing display:none as I suggested earlier ?

Comment: Yes, adding Display:none; to .content div just hides all the content for the div, including the tab content that is the focus.

Answer (score 0):

I would change your 3 things in your css:

1. first remove position:absolute; from .content div {}
2. remove the height:370px; from .content {}
3. replace 'float:left' to display:inline-block for .menu_items li{}

-- [Your fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/Ca3jb/1/)

the updated css for those elements would be:

```
.content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 3px;
}

.content div {
    padding: 10px 40px;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity linear 0.1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity linear 0.1s;
    -o-transition: opacity linear 0.1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity linear 0.1s;
    transition: opacity linear 0.1s;
}
.menu_items li{
    display:inline-block;
    width:340px;
}
```

Comment: Any further assistance from the community would be much appreciated.

Comment: @JasonBrown What further do you need assistance with?

Comment: I have applied the changes that @manuBriot and yourself suggested, and they kind of work, however if i implement the final suggestion by manuBriot namely change opacity: 0 to display:none in .content div this hides all the content for the ul. So as things stand I have had to keep .content div as opacity: 0, this means that the li are hidden but space is still reserved for it rather than the box resizing.

Comment: My answer only deals with your original question.. can you link your most updated fiddle, so I can see the issue you're talking about?

Comment: Thats exactly what Im looking for, what did you change?